# What is the most cheap way to mix `this` and other selectors in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

what is the best way to mix `this` with other selectors in JQuery  `:filter`,`[id=""]` and stuff like this, lets assume we wanna read `.val()` of an input with `name="input"` in form with that function is bind to it.

and if possible do they cost different ? if so why ?

here is the form

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="input">
</form>
```

like we have this

```
   $("form").submit(function(){

        if($(this).valid() == true){ //here  i wanna read the value of input with name test}
```

Comment: Can you post an example of elements you want to select?  I don't understand the question...how `this` fits in specifically.

Comment: Yeah but you can find it in question.

Comment: @omeid , this and filter does different tasks , we cannot compare them..

Comment: @Omeid - I read the question...I have no idea how `this` factors in at all, the selector is `$("#test input[name=input]")`...how does `this` come into play?

Comment: @moeid , one thumb rule is whenever you are using this make a local reference and use that instead of this/// this can improve the performance

Comment: @nick, hem now i got what you mean, updated the question!

Comment: Interesting, also would $(this).find('selector') or $('selector',$(this)) be equivalent or is one better performance wise?

Comment: @Tahbaza -The first would be faster, since the second goes through a few `if` checks and regexes...then gets converted to the first `.find()` version anyway.

Comment: @Nick : Thanks, I'll put that to good use

Comment: @Tahbaza is this interesting ? what the vote is for then? hahah,

Comment: @omeid +1 but next time try to be more clear (with code) so everyone gets your meaning easily

Comment: @Tahbaza, Sure! i will keep this in mind, even dough i have added code after asking! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selector would just be:

```
var myVal = $("#test input[name=input]").val();
```

The `this` version would use [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) like this:

```
var myVal = $(this).find("input[name=input]").val();
```

...which is faster depends on the browser and what it supports, namely if it supports querying by selectors relatively.

Comment: yeah your right the question was a bit wrong, now you know i have update and you can see where `this` comes from!

Comment: @nick it may depend on up how many input elements in this form right , if there are 100 elements first one might be better...right??any inputs

Comment: Thanks but querying selectors relatively isn't that what depends on JQuery ? and can you mention an other way cheaper or expensive maybe ? LOLZ.

Comment: @gov -it depends, does the browser support `querySelectorAll()`, does it support element selector matching? Or is it a Sizzle fallback in the case of neigher doing a `.getElementsByName()` (https://github.com/jeresig/sizzle/blob/master/sizzle.js#L452).

Comment: @Omeid - jQuery uses Sizzle for selectors...and it'll use very fast native browser methods for many things *if* the browser support them...if not it emulates the behavior, but it's of course slower than native code...so it depends what the browser does or doesn't support as to what's faster.

Comment: @Nick , do you reference some jquery books or documentation somewhere, or you got all these through experience, if you know any can you suggest some good book or material

Comment: @gov - experience mostly, and keeping up with the code base...not sure what other way to explain it than I remember pretty much everything I see or hear, it's a curse :) ...never read a jQuery or JavaScript book, so would be blindly suggesting there - would rather not.  There are however a few SO questions on which books are best for that, I'd check those out.

Comment: @Nice thanks very much , i like your quality of responding for each comment ///good one keep it up.

Comment: @gov - thanks :) here are 2 of those questions I'd check out, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60971/jquery-book-recommendation) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/96818/best-jquery-book-jquery-in-action-vs-learning-jquery)

Comment: @Nick: Thanks alot, i found new stuff to do, get in to the sizzle! i mean in-and-out!

Answer (score 1):

use [find](http://api.jquery.com/live/) maybe?

Comment: @breezer , if you understand the question , can you explain it once again.

Comment: I think the OP means 'grab some elements from an already-captured context'. So `$(this).find("input[name=input]").val()` is what he is after, IMO. But I could be completely wrong.

Comment: Will the question was a bit unclear now i have added some codes can someone check that out now ?

Comment: @omeid ,  it depends on no of input elements in your form , if you have few like 4 or 5 , it doesn't matter much

Comment: @gov yeah i understood it as karim79 did